# why the demo code in the book gives errors " Undefined index "

Tags: php, sql, forms

I am studying php. The book I am reading is "PHP and mysql web development".

For the code on Page394, it has errors as follows: 
[image]
Could you tell me what's wrong ?

The codes are as this:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ((!isset($name)) || (!isset($password)))
    {
?>
<h1>Please log in<h1>
<p> This page is secret.</p>
<form method="post" action="secret.php">
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in"></p>
</form>
<?php
}
else if (($name == "user") && ($password =="pass"))
{
    echo "<h1>Here it is</h1>";
    echo "<p>I bet you are glad you can see this secret page.</p>";
}
else{
    echo "<h1> Go Away</h1>";
    echo "<p>You are not authorized to use this </p>";
}
```

Comment: A little offtop: what mysql functions used in this book?

Comment: If you enter data in the fields then submit the form, you shouldn't see the error. Also if that is an actual snippet from the book, you should take it back, as the example is horrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the `$_POST` values, then assignment. Your doing the inverse.

Should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Could you tell me what's wrong?

You are not attentive enough. Your book has additional symbol at the beginning of the lines.

```
@    $name = $_POST['name'];
@    $password = $_POST['password'];
```

`@` - suppress errors.

My suggestion:

**Do not use this book. It's old and ugly.**

Comment: Wow, agreed. Any book which teaches how to suppress errors is garbage.

Comment: Could you give any suggestions: which book is good? Thanks !!

Comment: @tqjustc, so... bad book with typos :^ ) http://ahvaz.ist.unomaha.edu/azad/temp/softarch/05-welling-php-mysql-web.pdf 394 pdf page

Comment: @tqjustc, I have never read a book to learn PHP :^ ) This book looks actual: http://www.amazon.com/PHP-Cookbook-Solutions-Examples-Programmers/dp/144936375X/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1418360878&sr=8-8&keywords=php+book

Comment: @sectus Good. The first one you give me is the book I am reading. but mine is fourth edition. On the version you give me, the demo code is correct. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @tqjustc , year of 'fourth edition' is 2008. There was php 5.2 version. Now actual version 5.6. And there is a lot of changes and improvements. The first link to show where I've got `@` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

If you are submitting to the same page where your form is located then you should do this:

```
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : "";
```

The native function `isset` check if the variable exists.

Comment: Variable in this context is a misnomer, rather you are checking for the existence of a specific key in the array, and that it doesn't have a null value.